# How to get music from Dropbox to ANY mp3 music type app

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, unix, dropbox

I am using an iphone 6, first time with an iphone, not really fond of it unfortunately bought it for the slow-mo video but having a heck of a time getting my music transferred!

I don't want to live stream it, I want the music saved on my iphone. Trying to transfer from a Linux system computer (that was a whole lot of fun) finally figured that out using the dropbox app, but how to get the music from dropbox to an app that I can make playlists and NOT stream as I don't have unlimited data or wifi available ( I know stone age right?)! There has got to be an answer. Don't want to pay for all the music I had on my android device before switching to (cough.. a phone known for music abilities)... help appreciated! (as user friendly as possible I am tec illiterate, sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

It's really not possible to get music from Dropbox into the music app on your iPhone. Apple does not support getting music onto your iPhone that way. The Dropbox app will play the songs but is hardly a music playing app.

You mention Linux. Do you have a Mac or a Windows PC? The best way is to add the songs to iTunes on a Mac or Windows PC and then sync your files using iTunes. Apple does not make iTunes for Linux and iTunes is the only *supported* way to get music from your computer onto your iPhone.

Not being a Linux guy there **may** be a Linux application that will get the music onto your iPhone without iTunes. Maybe there is a Linux guy here that knows if there is such a thing. **I** don't know, sorry.

Apple is all about making it simple to do basic things for the majority of people. Those of us at the geeky/nerdy end of the spectrum often face these frustrations. You can either continue to be frustrated, or just relax and do it the Apple way, using Apple software. There are a number of things that have always annoyed me about Apple software and Macs (+ iPhones...) in general. But I have learned to accept the limitations because I don't like Windows and Linux just annoys me. But that is just me, you have to do what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [CloudBeats](http://www.cloudbeatsapp.com/) app. I haven't used the app personally (and am not affiliated with it), but I've come across it before while contemplating a similar situation. I believe its features meet your needs:

- It can connect to your Dropbox account (along with various other cloud services) to play audio files
- It can download files for offline playback
- It allows you to create playlists, potentially combining files from multiple sources

The app has a [free version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudbeats-lite-cloud-music/id681144772) with limited features, but that should at least give you a sense of if it would be useful. The full app costs five bucks.

Answer (score 0):

Jukebox app is free and does what you want.  It will scan your Dropbox for music, and then download what you select. And it's free.  The music player is limited but it's offline listening with no need for a data connection.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Linux, but I do have a pc and an iphone. I can download anything that is in my dropbox directly to my pc.  If it's music, then I save them in a folder or put them wherever I want. Then, I open iTunes that I've already installed on my computer. I locate "add file" in iTunes and add the new music I just downloaded to my pc. 
Connect the iphone to the computer while iTunes is open.  ITunes will notice the phone and you'll see it listed in the drop down menu. Locate the music from your music tifles on the screen that you want to add to your phone.  Click and drag over to your phone device in the drop down menu and it is instantly put onto your iphone.
This is my first iphone (after years of Android) and I spent many hours of frustration, until I finally figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the [Online Playlist](http://www.online-playlist.com/) service. They have a [demo](http://www.online-playlist.com/dropbox-player.html).

This is Online Dropbox player, it works with any Web-browser, even with iPhone Safari! Just upload your mp3/ogg to your DB account and enjoy it via this player.

No additional software, no files synchronization with Dropbox.

That's it!